# Unable to determine the results of a Google Groups search using Javascript in a Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, obfuscation, google-groups

I'm writing a Chrome extension that searches for posts in a Google Group whose subject lines contain a given character string. From the browser, using the search query "subject:", I get the search results: either 0 results or > 0 and I take different actions depending on whether results come up. The wrinkle is that if I simply fetch the page data for the results page using, say,

```
try
  {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open("GET", url, false);
  request.send(null);
  }
catch (e)
  {
  console.log(e);   
  return;
  }
if (request.status == 200)
  {
  var tmp = request.responseText;
  }
```

I just get obfuscated data and can't read it. If I can get a Document object back, then I can search for a certain classname, with something like doc.getElementsByClassName, that exists if and only there are non-zero results from the search.

Comment: My previous "answer" is unsatisfactory and kludgy; anyone got a better idea? There has to be a way to turn a string of HTML data to a document.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to turn the responseText to a dom....

```
var page = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
page.documentElement.innerHTML = request.responseText;
// Now you can find things
var thing = page.documentElement.querySelector('#find');
```

...but this won't always be enough for some pages as they are ajax driven and the new Google Groups is for sure.
So this page is just the frame for all the other stuff the js is going to get when the page is loaded.
Somtimes you can figure how to replicate the ajax request the page makes and replicate it by looking at the Network panel in the WebInspector and watch what happens when you press the search button.
But Google Groups 2 is doing some funky stuff and I wouldn't have a clue ;)
There's other things you can do like override XMLHttpRequest and monitor what calls it and what it does when the ready state changes to 4 or monitor the onload.  And use that info to try and figure out what function processes the responseText and sometimes find what you need that way.  But I can't find my code for that at the moment and dont really feel inclined to do it for this as I know its not going to be pretty ;)
Good Luck.